# Bulk Data Delete in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

This is my code:

```
HTTParty.delete("http://#{SERVER_DOMAIN}:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/_query?q=id:11321779,11321779", { 
    })
```

I want to delete data in bulk using id but this query is not deleting data from elasticsearch

Can anyone help me figuring out how can I delete data in bulk?

Comment: Which ruby client do you use to connect to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index_name should be as provided as per the index name in your code. Provide the ids to be deleted in the array(1,2,3).

CGI::escape is the URL encoder.

```
HTTParty.delete "http://#{SERVER_DOMAIN}:9200/index_name/_query?source=#{CGI::escape("{\"terms\":{\"_id\":[1,2,3]}}")}"
```

This actually uses the delete by query api of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you are using **tire ruby client** to connect to elasticsearch:

```
id_array = [1,2,3]
query = Tire.search do |search|
        search.query { |q| q.terms :_id, id_array }
      end

index = Tire.index('<index_name>') # provide the index name as you have in your code

Tire::Configuration.client.delete "#{index.url}/_query?source=#{Tire::Utils.escape(query.to_hash[:query].to_json)}"
```

Reference: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/309

Answer (score 0):

Provision is provided using: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-bulk.html

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "index1"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

OR

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty' -d '
{"update":{"_id":"1"}}
{"doc": { "name": "John Doe becomes Jane Doe" } }
{"delete":{"_id":"2"}}
'
```

Refer : [How to handle multiple updates / deletes with Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625066/how-to-handle-multiple-updates-deletes-with-elasticsearch)