# How to handle multiple updates / deletes with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, bulkupdate, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I need to update or delete several documents.

When I update I do this:

1. I first search for the documents, setting a greater limit for the returned results (let’s say, size: 10000).
2. For each of the returned documents, I modify certain values.
3. I resent to elasticsearch the whole modified list (bulk index).

This operation takes place until point 1 no longer returns results.

When I delete I do this:

1. I first search for the documents, setting a greater limit for the returned results (let’s say, size: 10000)
2. I delete every found document sending to elasticsearch _id document (10000 requests)

This operation repeats until point 1 no longer returns results.

Is this the right way to make an update?

When I delete, is there a way I can send several ids to delete multiple documents at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deletion and update, if you want to delete or update by id you can use the bulk api:

> **Bulk API**
>
> The bulk API makes it possible to perform many index/delete operations
>   in a single API call. This can greatly increase the indexing speed.
>
> The possible actions are index, create, delete and update. index and
>   create expect a source on the next line, and have the same semantics
>   as the op_type parameter to the standard index API (i.e. create will
>   fail if a document with the same index and type exists already,
>   whereas index will add or replace a document as necessary). delete
>   does not expect a source on the following line, and has the same
>   semantics as the standard delete API. update expects that the partial
>   doc, upsert and script and its options are specified on the next line.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

You can also delete by query instead:

> **Delete By Query API**
>
> The delete by query API allows to delete documents from one or more
>   indices and one or more types based on a query. The query can either
>   be provided using a simple query string as a parameter, or using the
>   Query DSL defined within the request body.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: What would you recommend between "delete by query" and "bulk delete" (see @Tom83 's answer)? Have you used them both?

Comment: Yes, I've used them both. Bulk delete is more useful if you have a discrete list of document ids that you want deleted. Delete by query is better if you have a single query that identifies all the documents you want to delete. As always, which to use depends on your use case.

Comment: not sure if this is for the current version of delete by query, but for what i saw the current delete by query uses scroll and bulk, so if you have already the list of ids to delete maybe you should use just bulk https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/delete-by-query-plugin-reason.html#_new_delete_by_query_implementation

Answer (score 5):

For your massive index/update operation, if you don't use it already (not sure), you can take a look at the [bulk api documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk). it is tailored for this kind of job.

If you want to retrieve lots of documents by small batches, you should use the `scan-scroll` search instead of using `from/size`. Related information can be found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan).

To sum up :

- `scroll` api is used to load results in memory and to be able to iterate over it efficiently
- `scan` search type disable sorting, which is costly

Give it a try, depending on the data volume, it could improve the performance of your batch operations.

For the delete operation, you can use this same `_bulk` api to send multiple delete operation at once.

The format of each line is the following :

```
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "indexName", "_type" : "typeName", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "indexName", "_type" : "typeName", "_id" : "2" } }
```

Comment: It seems I cannot use scan-scroll because the update will change a value of a field that is used to return the results. So I always use {from: 0} and change just the "size" param to make fewer requests. But it's good to know for the future. The bulk delete is what I was looking for. What would you recommend between "delete by query" and "bulk delete"?

Comment: As you want to delete all the documents matching one query, I would use delete by query for convenience : you will be able to skip the first step (retrieving all the ids of the matching documents). I don't know about performances though.